# Прогнозирование завершения обучения в Excel

Tags: excel

Есть дата начала обучения (например, 01.09.2019). Образовательная программа рассчитана на 3 месяца (т.е. ровно до 01.12.2019), за это время человек должен пройти 18 курсов. Строится таблица, где есть дата начала обучения, дата окончания обучения и количество пройденных за текущий период курсов по каждому сотруднику (например, один прошел 5 курсов, другой 10 итд).
Вопрос - каким образом, например, с помощью функции =ПРЕДСКАЗ мы можем рассчитать динамику обучения, т.е. предсказать в %, с какой вероятностью человек закончит к 01.12.2019 всю учебную программу, 18 курсов?

Comment: Чё тут предсказывать-то? Сколько надо дней на курс - известно (судя по всему, они одинаковы, иначе необходим список пройденных курсов). Тупо множим на количество оставшихся курсов и сравниваем с колитчеством оставшихся дней. Если дней меньше - 100% товарищ в пролёте, иначе фиг знает (но 100% что он МОЖЕТ успеть, если не филонить). А для предсказаний тут никаких оснований нету - function CrystalBall() is not defined...

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Все получилось!